# Updating rows over 2 tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having problems updating 2 tables with related models. I can get 1 table to be edited on its own.  I have checked around the docs and here and I cant find this simple answer as yet.

What I get is a new row and not an edited row.

The docs say this is because I don't have an id field which isn't true.
I can fiddle around and try to get it working but I prefer a conventional way as do I need to use `saveAssociated`? What is the method to save over more than 1 related table?

The User table has a id field and the Teacher table had the user_id foreign key.

Now before I posted I checked `saveAll`, `updateAll` and other posts here.

The 1 models are `User` and `Teacher`. A `User` `hasOne` `Teacher` and a `Teacher` `belongsTo` a `User`.

I am not sure if `saveAll` or `updateAll` is the way to go because it doesn't talk about edits much in the docs but add new.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

[CakePHP - Updating multiple tables at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043445/cakephp-updating-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time)

**View Code**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.username');   //text
    echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.firstname');   //text
    echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.surname');  
    echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.address');   //text
    echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.suburb'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.phone'); 
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

**Controller Code**

```
<?php
public function editteacher($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->User->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your techer has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'teachers', 'action' => 'displayall'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My inclination is that you need to store the `id` of the record as either a URL parameter, or as a hidden field in your form.

```
 <?php


     echo $this->Form->create('User');
     // Added this next line
     echo $this->Form->hidden('User.id');
     echo $this->Form->input('User.username');   //text
     // Added this line too (if necessary)
     echo $this->Form->hidden('Teacher.id');
     echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.firstname');   //text
     echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.surname');  
     echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.address');   //text
     echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.suburb'); 
     echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.phone'); 
     echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');

 ?>
```

You need to include the record `id`'s of  the items you wish to update, otherwise it will create new records.

Comment: I tried updateall and hidden fields. I got a new row or a error user.user doesnt exist. The update all just has the this-request-data as the array? I am still stuck sorry

Comment: @ajt As already mentioned, do _not_ use `updateAll()`, use either [**`save()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) or [**`saveAssociated()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array). And maybe check the [**blog tutorial**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#editing-posts).

Comment: this was my original post and you are saying go back to it? You have not offered  any alternative so I am none the wiser

Comment: use `save` or `saveAll` like ndm said

Comment: if you look at my code in my original post I do use saveALL. However I added hidden fields and this works. This is not in the docs and is very confusing

Comment: @ajt I didn't say use `saveAll`, actually I said use `save` or `saveAssocaited`. While `saveAll` should theoretically work too, I personally prefer using the explicit method that would be used by `saveAll` anyways, and that would be `saveAssociated`. You have accepted the answer so I guess your problem is fixed?